# Would dropping LDAP callbacks prevent Log4Shell

Tags: ldap, log4j, firewall, log4shell

I am trying to upgrade my log4j version to 2.15.0. This should take me a while as I have to upgrade other stuff as well. My question is does dropping ldap callbacks on both 363 and 636 ports on my server will prevent the log4shell attack?

Comment: This may benefit from similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70440185/log4j-backward-compatibility (can jar be replaced without any further development required?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid not as the attacker can specify a different port in the attack string.