# Log4j 2.17 binary backward compatibility - direct replacement

Tags: log4j, upgrade, backwards-compatibility, semantic-versioning, log4shell

Can I simply replace log4j-**core**-2.x (e.g. 2.8.2) with 2.17.1 **without breaking backward compatibility**? In other words, is Log4j project following [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/)?

[Log4J official changelog](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/changelog.html) does not provide any clear statement on that. But this would be a dramatic simplification in the remediation process.

Bonus question: is this also true for log4j-**api**-2.x?

Answer (score 2):

There has been some API breakage in `log4j-core`, so it is not strictly semantically versioned. The only one I am aware of is:

- The `ConfigurationFactory#getConfiguration` methods got an additional `LoggerContext` parameter (see [LOG4J2-1547](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1547)). This can prevent a Log4j upgrade in old Spring Boot 1.2.x versions (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70578685/11748454)).

However, this might be the only exception to semantic versioning, so you should upgrade the library and see if everything works.